# How can I use mp3 sounds in my Android cocos2d project so as to not increase the size of apk to 25MB

Tags: android, audio, cocos2d-android

We are developing one game in Android with cocos2d. Now as per out scenario, we have more than 20MB of just mp3 sound files which occupy the whole lot space of our final apk. Can anyone suggest us a simpler and tactical way to efficiently use all existing sounds in mp3 sounds simultaneously not to increase apk size to more than 25 MB?? Its really urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With many games with large resources, after downloading they actually will connect to a server download the MP3 or high-resolution textures into a known directory. Check out the DataStorage API for more information about this.

Just make sure you cover the case where the user does not have these MP3 files on their device, whether it was because they decided not to download them, doesn't have internet acccess or deleted them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but as a part of development process, we are forced to put all these mp3 resources with the game itself and these will reside in client's phone (i.e. SDCard). The option you suggested is already taken into consideration by us, but it is not approved by our client.. :(

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure what to say. You have 20+ MB of sounds and you can't package it with the APK and it can't be downloaded seperately. Being in this situation before, I would tell my client that it will have no sounds.

Comment: Hmmm, may be it could happen!! :-)